# Any reasons not to use SQLObject over SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, sqlobject

I don't expect to need much more than basic CRUD type functionality. I know that SQLAlchemy is more flexible, but the syntax etc of sqlobject just seem to be a bit easier to get up and going with.

Comment: There are many wrappers for sqlalchemy which make it as easy as sqlobject. such as elixir and quick_orm.

Answer (score 9):

I think SQLObject is more pythonic/simpler, so if it works for you, then stick with it.
SQLAlchemy takes a little more to learn, but can do more advanced things if you need that.

Answer (score 7):

Also, you  might wanna take a look at [elixir](http://elixir.ematia.de/trac/wiki), which is a fairly thick wrapper around SQLAlchemy and really makes the basic tasks easy while retaining the power of SQLA.

Comment: Check Quick ORM: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/quick_orm. It's a SQLAlchemy wrapper too.

Answer (score 0):

Try quick_orm. It is as powerful as SQLAlchemy and simpler than SQLObject.

https://github.com/tylerlong/quick_orm